# Problems with CSS div layout and IE7

Tags: css, layout, internet-explorer-7

I am currently developing a new website and have problems with IE7. First image is what it should look like. Second image is what IE7 renders (I use IETester to test older IE versions).

The **first** problem is with the white background which is applied with the following trick. There is a div that contains both left and right column with `background-color: white`; The left column has the same background as the page (and some `padding-right`) so that even if the right column' height is less that left's they appear to have equal height.

The **second** is with the list (`ul`) below the dummy text, which appears really messed up.

At first I thought that this would be easily solved with some "clear: both" here and there, but it didn't. I've tried lots of things but with no luck.

Any idea what I should do?

Tia,
Nikos.

Modern Browsers:
[image: This is what it should look like]

IE7:
[image: This is what it looks like in IE7]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I solved the problems mentioned, after I read some articles about [hasLayout](http://www.satzansatz.de/cssd/onhavinglayout.html). By applying specific width or `zoom: 1` (there are other ways too in the previous link) to certain divs that didn't wrap or clear properly, everything seems ok now.